# Difference between ". myscript" and "./myscript"

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am confused by "one only dot - space - shell script name" (like `. myshellscript`) and "path to shell script" (like `./myshellscript`) commands.

What for they are? I noticed the command `. myshellscript` executes shell script even with -rw-rw-r--. But `./myshellscript` doesn't. So I am confused.

Comment: When in doubt, use `./foo`. That *executes* the script, which you usually want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Others have said the difference is sourcing vs executing but no one has outlined the *functional* differences.

The biggest functional difference is that `exit`, `cd`, and variable assignments will affect the currently running shell if you source it, but not if you execute it. To demonstrate, try the following:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p test
cd test
pwd

foo=bar
echo script foo: $foo

$ ./test.sh
/Users/kevin/test
script foo: bar
$ echo $foo

$ pwd
/Users/kevin
$ . test.sh
/Users/kevin/test
script foo: bar
$ echo $foo
bar
$ pwd
/Users/kevin/test
$
```

Now try this:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
exit
$ ./test.sh
$ . test.sh

[Process completed]
```

As you can see, `exit` in an executed script will finish that script, but if you source a script with `exit`, it will exit your current shell!

Answer (score 20):

`help source` says:

```
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
    entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
    If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
    when FILENAME is executed.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
    FILENAME cannot be read.
```

`source` is a synonym for `.`, that means you can write both

```
. myshellscript
```

or

```
source myshellscript
```

What they do: `source` reads every line of the file (line by line) and executes it in the current shell.

But `./myshellscript` **executes** the file in the current directory if it has the rights to do so. This could also be

```
/tmp/foo/bar/myshellscript
```

(to execute the file `myshellscript` which is in the directory `/tmp/foo/bar`) or

```
/usr/local/bin/myshellscript
```

That means, that here the dot is just the *current directory*. Therefore `./myshellscript` executes the file called `myshellscript` in the current directory.

For example try

```
cd .
```

which changes to the current directory (no real change ;-)) or

```
ls .
```

which lists the content of the current directory.

---

And as @Alvin Wong commented: You can try this script

```
#!/bin/foobarNonExisting

echo "This is the Shell that executes me:"
echo $SHELL
```

with `.` or `source` to see, that it does not read the shebang. It just uses your current shell. Executing the script itself would lead to an error.

Comment: @YarLinux you haven't set the executable bit on `myshellscript`. Run `chmod u+x myshellscript` and try again.

Comment: Because `source myshellscript` does **not** execute the script. But reads every line of the file (line by line) and executes it. That is a difference. And this only works if your file **is** a shell script. A python script wont work. Neither a binary file. For them you only have the `./mypythonfile` option. Or `python mypythonfile`.

Comment: Oh? So it means that using `.` or `source` doesn't read the shebang, and `sh` script will be executed by `bash`?

Comment: @Alvin Wong Exactly.

Answer (score 9):

In bash, `.` and `source` functionally perform the same job -- running a script inside the current shell.

`./foo` runs inside another shell, as your shell forks before execution.

If your script should be portable, always use `.`. `source` is a bash synonym, but it does not exist in POSIX.

Comment: *"...the POSIX shell."*  There is no *the* POSIX shell.  POSIX is a [set of specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), not a particular program.  Any shell implementation which follows the specifications is *a* POSIX shell.  (Most POSIX shells, including bash, extend the specified behavior with additional functionality.)

Comment: Yes, it should be *a* POSIX shell, not *the*. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`.` is a synonym to the `source` command. Instead of forking a sub shell to execute the script it reads the script into the current shell environment.  In other words `./script` will execute the script in a spawned sub shell and does the processing there. Where `. script` reads the script into your current shell where your current shell will process the commands.

They do the similar things. With `. script` you are *reading* and `./script` you are *executing* (by spawning a sub shell) so the appropriate permissions are required to do either.

Comment: Effectively they do a different thing, try running a script containing `exit`.

Comment: You're right.  I changed it.  I hadn't thought of that originally.

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers explaining that `. ~/bin/script.sh` is equivalent to `source ~/bin/script.sh`. Here's the explanation of **why**.

I have several clusters that I use for testing, and I use environment variables to point to them. Normally when you run a script, any variables set in it stay in the scope of that script. In example:

```
$ echo $MYFIELD #Nothing set

$ cat test.sh
export MYFIELD=foo #This would set it
$ ./test.sh
$ echo $MYFIELD #Didn't work because the script didn't carry it back to its parent

$ . ./test.sh
$ echo $MYFIELD #When run as a sourced script, this stayed in the context of my current shell
foo
```

In this way, I can type `. ~/env/cluster7` and then run any commands I want on that cluster, then type `. ~/env/cluster3` to change all my environment variables to point to another one without having to manually set them.

Notice that "." at the start of a line followed by a space is interpreted as a command. This is OK because you'd never execute the only file that can be named that way: the current directory. In any other context, though, such as without a following space or at any point later in the command line, it refers to the path, hence `. ./test.sh`. Since it is considered a command by bash, `. test.sh` also works.

Comment: So, to paraphrase this as a **when**... you would use `.` (or `source`) when you want to run a set of shell commands from a file in order to set environment variables or change the current directory in your *current* shell process (the shell *from which* you're running the `source` command).