# How to export environmental variables in a Posix shell script?

Tags: linux

**Goal:** Create a Posix compatible sh script that uses an environment variable created by a sourced script.

**/dir/var.sh** contains only the following to create an environment variable.

```
export IPTABLES="/usr/sbin/iptables"
```

**/dir/startup.sh** contains the following.

```
#!/bin/sh

. /dir/var.sh

$IPTABLES options

command1 #Does not use an environmental variable
```

After `startup.sh` completes, the variable is either not created or does not survive. Why ?

Note: the OS firmware is read-only. It does not allow editing the /etc/profile file to set environment variables to be available to all shells. Any script to export variables will execute too late.

Comment: A *called* script is very different from a *sourced* script.  Your question says "called" but your code shows "sourced."  Which do you want?

Comment: (Also, just based on the type of questions you are asking, you may be interested in using a mature configuration management tool such as CFEngine, the original purpose of which was to abstract away differences between *nix-like operating systems.)

Comment: No.  You can call a script or you can source a script.  They are completely different actions.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65634/135943

Comment: Your problem here is likely one of relative paths vs. absolute paths.  The startup.sh script as written will only work correctly if you run it from the `/` directory (i.e. run `cd /` first).

Comment: There are other commands in the startup.sh script that execute correctly. Execution of the startup.sh script is controlled by the OS at bootup so I don't know where the working directory is.

Comment: See previous comment.  And *carefully* learn the following concepts: absolute path, relative path, *current working directory* (of a *process*).  Then reread the command `. ./dir/var.sh` and see if you can spot what's wrong.

Comment: Okay, I'll spell it out: **replace `. ./dir/var.sh` with `. /dir/var.sh` and your script will work.**  This has nothing to do with environment variables, only to do with paths.

Comment: This question isn't much different than the behavior of bashrc or profile files

Comment: IIUC, you want to create environment variables that would be available to all processes, including already started processes and processes that you don't start yourself. You cannot. In Unix, environment is inherited by processes. Thus, you must set your environment in a grand-...-grand-parent-process, which would probably be init itself, or an early init script. Since your firmware is read-only, you cannot do that.

Comment: This question is misleading; your actual question is about creating a globally-available environment variable, but immediately dives in to talking about a sourced script that sets and exports a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [related Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable):

> In Unix, an environment variable that is changed in a script or
>   compiled program will only affect that process and possibly child
>   processes. The parent process and any unrelated processes will not be
>   affected.

Sourcing (*) is including a script in the current processing. Environment variables defined in your `var.sh` script are thus seen from the `startup.sh` script.

OTOH, `startup.sh` is called, not sourced. It's therefore a child process as mentioned in the WP page. All variables created in this script will be discarded when the script ends.

(*) `source script.sh` or `. script.sh`. As stated by others in the OP's comments, it is a bad idea to specify a relative path to the source script as you did with `. ./dir/var.sh` since it depends on the location where you are calling `startup.sh` from.

Comment: This doesn't apply.  Look closer.  The variables defined in `var.sh` are *not* seen from `startup.sh`, because it's sourced with a *relative path* which is incorrect for the current working directory in which `startup.sh` is actually run.

Comment: @Wildcard How do you know the current working directory is not `/`? The question is "**After** startup.sh runs, the variables are not created or do not survive", not why `IPTABLES` is not defined in `startup.sh`.

Comment: The question is badly and imprecisely written, but also note the statement in comments "there are other commands in the startup.sh script that execute correctly," implying that some do *not*.  And as for creating a "sh script that uses an environment variable created by a called script," the environment variable is created by a *sourced* script, not a called script.  So your mistake is understandable, but it just goes to show you shouldn't answer a question that needs further clarification.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard Still not sure I misunderstood the question, but concur with the fact that the whole post is poorly written. OTOH the last question, the one I quoted above, is unambiguous.

Comment: In a Windows environment, we say calling. In this example on Linux, I learned there is a distinction between the words calling and sourcing. The OP has been updated to reflect this. That said, changing to ". ./" to ". /" didn't fix the variables not being created or surviving.

Comment: @uihdff Can you clarify your question and/or answer to Wildcard in the question's comments? You didn't accept my answer so I'm still unsure that I understood it well.

Comment: @uihdff, a child process changing its own environment variables can never affect the environment of its parent—exactly as stated in the quote from Wikipedia in this answer.  If what you really want is to set environment variables in a way that they will be available in *any shell that you run,* that's a completely different question and you should use an `rc` file or `profile` file of some sort, perhaps `~/.bashrc`.